# How to focus on JTextField within a table

Tags: java, swing, jtable, jtextfield

I'm writing a search & replace function in a kind of spreadsheet program. What I want is that if you search for a string, the program shows a table with the element that has been found.

So far so good, but I cannot get the element to obtain the focus, with the cursor in it so you can immediately start typing.

I'm using a customized `JTable` and also a customized `TableCellEditor`. The following tricks do not seem to work:
(within the customized `TableCellEditor`):

```
SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new Runnable() { 
    public void run() { 
        my_textfield.requestFocus(); 
    } 
});
```

or:

```
my_jtable.editCellAt(0, 3);
my_jtable.requestFocus();
```

or

```
my_jtable.getEditorComponent().requestFocusInWindow();
```

Am I missing something? Is there a good description (nice flow diagram) that shows how events take place? Or example code that might do something similar?

Comment: For now, I kind of gave up on this one. It's probably related to having multiple components within others (using internalFrames's, and therein a splitframe that contains both a JTree and the table).

If I have time, I will try to start-out with a very clean attempt and see where it will break

Answer (score 2):

With some googling i found a forum thread : [programmatically start editing a cell in a JTable](http://coding.derkeiler.com/Archive/Java/comp.lang.java.gui/2006-06/msg00188.html) answered with following idea:

(in a subclass of JTable)

```
editCellAt(row,column);

requestFocus();
DefaultCellEditor ed = (DefaultCellEditor)
getCellEditor(row,column);

ed.shouldSelectCell(new ListSelectionEvent(this,row,row,true));
```

Would it work?

Comment: I *think* the last line should be ...(this,row,column,true));

I'm not sure if I tried the exact sequence as written above, but I will check it out.

Comment: I think the (this, row, row, true) is the correct - the constructor is  : ListSelectionEvent(Object source, int firstIndex, int lastIndex, boolean isAdjusting) - so the row is the only index to be selected..

Answer (score 0):

Did you try the editcellat without the requestfocus ?

also make sure that you override/implemenet to return true

```
    /**
     * Returns true.
     * @param anEvent  an event object
     * @return true
     */
    public boolean shouldSelectCell(EventObject anEvent) { 
    return true; 
    }
```

Comment: No, this does not work. I also added a println in the above function just to see if it gets called. But it only gets called if I do the call explicitly:

StructureCellEditor sce = (StructureCellEditor) my_table.getCellEditor(0, 3);
sce.shouldSelectCell(...);

Comment: Note that above the StructureCellEditor is my own extended TableCellEditor

Answer (score 0):

Check if you have enabled selection on your custom table instance like below:

```
table.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
table.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
```

With this being set, generally a call to `table.editCellAt(row, col);` starts editing. Example :

```
JTable myTable = new JTable(rows, cols);
myTable.setColumnSelectionAllowed(true);
myTable.setRowSelectionAllowed(true);
```

and somewhere else..where edit is needed,

```
boolean wasEditStarted = table.editCellAt(row, col);
if (wasEditStarted) {
  table.changeSelection(row, col, false, false);
}
```